# Send ImageView to another activity

Tags: android

I have an activity with an `ImageView` and I want to send this `ImageView` in an other activity, how can I do this?

Comment: you can't pass views between activities.

Comment: ok..so how can I "import" that imageview in the other activity ?

Comment: you can have another imageview in your second activity and set the image to the imageview.

Comment: I created another imageview in my second activity but how can I set it to the first activity ? Thanks

Comment: You can put original image, let's say into cache, and pass id of that image to another activity, where you create and instance of the new ImageView.

Comment: what is that you intend to do. pls edit and elaborate your question

Comment: ok thansk for your advice.. but can you translate this with an example code please ?

Comment: you getting image in string form or wat??

Comment: I have "cameraActivity" in which I pick a photo and save it in a imageview . then i want to send this photo in the next activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot pass imageviews between activties.

Assuming you need to pass the image from one activity to another.

You can pass bitmap by converting it to bytearray as below

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
```

Pass byte array into intent:-

```
Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("picture", byteArray);
startActivity(intent);
```

In NextActivity Get Byte Array from Bundle and Convert into Bitmap Image:-

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
byte[] byteArray = extras.getByteArray("picture");
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
image.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

**Update : 5-9-2019**
Note: It is better to store the image in some place on the disk and then pass only the path to the image to next activity. The above might not work if the image is huge.

Comment: I had a java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: @user2550055 start a new thread with relevant details. The above works fine. Post the code and stacktrace in a new question

Comment: @user2550055 exceptions might be because some object in your code might be null.

Answer (score 2):

You can't actually pass the ImageView itself. You can however, pass it's value and re-load that in your other Activity in it's own new ImageView.

You can pass data between Activitys in the intent.

This goes per example like this;

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyNewActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("EXTRA_IMAGEVIEW_URL", myImageViewData);
startActivity(intent)
```

Then in the started (MyNewActivity) you can fetch that data again;

```
String imageview_url = getIntent().getStringExtra("EXTRA_IMAGEVIEW_URL");
```

Use whatever method is appropriate for your type of data.

edit note:
This solution is assuming that you send a simple pointer to the image, not the image itself. You either send the URL or URI from where you load it, your drawable ID or the image path in your file system. Indeed, do not try to send the whole image itself as a base64, binary or whatever you come up with.

Comment: Thanks Stefan, I will try to do this

Comment: there is possibility of OOM if the image is too big. better compress it decode it on the receiving side.

Comment: This solution is assuming that you send a simple pointer to the image, not the image itself. You either send the URL or URI from where you load it, your drawable ID or the image path in your file system. Indeed, do not try to send the whole image itself as a base64, binary or whatever you come up with.

Comment: @StefandeBruijn add this to your answer instead of a comment for clarity

Comment: @StefandeBruijn in the code "myImageViewData" refer to the ImageView, it's correct ?

Comment: No, `myImageViewData` should be whatever you used to load your ImageView with for the first time. The URL, URI, Drawable ID, image path...

Answer (score 0):

you can either subclass imageview and implement serializable interface and pass it with this way or you can pass resource id(int) of imageview to another activity then load that activity's imageview with this resource id or you make imageview static and then at the other acitvity you simply call it via FirstClass.imageView

Answer (score 0):

Passing bitmap by converting it to bytearray works fine with me